# Meteor: prevent server restart upon changing server-side global variables

Tags: meteor

Where is the best place to store global variables that is required for the server only, and can avoid server restarts?

As of now, I am storing sensitive keys on the server. I understand that any code changes made in the server directory causes the application to restart.

As I may re-generate api keys in the future for security purposes, is there a way I can avoid this by storing the global variables in the 'private' directory?

If so, how can I do this?

e.g (my code as of now)

server > server.js

```
var privateKey = 'sensitive-values' 
//how to prevent server restart if I change the 'sensitive-values'?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit any file in the project, including in the private directory, the server will restart.

In production mode however, this will not be the case. It would be cumbersome to edit a production application, though.

It may be better to store `sensitive-values` in an environment variable.

```
var privateKey = process.env.SENSITIVEVALUE
```

Then start your meteor app using `SENSITIVEVALUE='sensitive-values' meteor` instead of just `meteor` or using [export](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-linux/) to store the environment variable for your terminal session.

This way the variable isn't stored in a file so it's not subject to being sensitive to being restarted.

Comment: I see. This answers my question. Thank you Akshat. I am considering the options for production mode.